# Does Twig allow assignments in conditions and how?

Tags: twig

As per title, does Twig allow assignments in conditional and how? I know that not all people like these assignments but sometimes they can be very helpful.

This:

```
{% if (name = attribute(mappings, property)) is defined %}
    {% else %}
    {% set attrs = attrs|merge(['%s="%s"'|format(name, value)]) %}
{% endif %}
```

...is not working and gives me and error:

> An opened parenthesis is not properly closed. Unexpected token
>   "operator" of value "=" ("punctuation" expected with value ")") in
>   ::tooltips.html.twig at line 29.

Comment: I seriously doubt this is possible. Twig is a templating engine and therefor you should generally strive for simple stupid templates with as little logic in them as possible.

Comment: @gilden we'll see. And by the way i partially agree with you. In a quite complex application with many macros you need to put some (maybe not so stupid) kind of logic in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your twig error is because of this line

```
{% if (name = attribute(mappings, property)) is defined %}
```

Twig doesn't like assignment-in-condition expressions, and personally neither do I, it's just a lazy shortcut and the potential issues isn't worth saving a few keystrokes.

But I have to now admit that I'm confused by what this is supposed to do. You're attempting to capture the result of `attribute(mappings, property)` into `name` but if that fails, *only then* do you do something using `name`, but by then `name` won't have a value unless it's been defined elsewhere in the template.

Comment: It would be great to have a reference to the documentation. Out of curiosity `name` is initialized before that conditional.